# How to insert new text at the bottom of the pdf file in golang?

Tags: go, pdf

I have `[]byte` content of pdf file, so I want to add new text at the bottom of it.

I've already tried to use https://github.com/ledongthuc/pdf and https://github.com/signintech/pdft libraries. They provide the method, `func (i *PDFt) Insert(text string, pageNum int, x float64, y float64, w float64, h float64, align int)`, but I could not identify the necessary line to insert my text, because I do not know content of this pdf file.

How to add new text ? Are there any approaches to do that ?

how it should work ?

1. before my adding
   [image]
2. after my adding new text
   [image]

as you notice, new text is `Председатель заседания Умаров А. О.`

Comment: The text at the bottom in your before/after images appear to be the same.

Comment: @nishanthshanmugham yeah, you are right! fixed the picture